# Why do I get a "parse error before '@' token" when I try to build this simple XCode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, accessor

Complete newbie question.  I'm learning Objective-C from Kochan's book.  When I try to build the following very simple project, I keep getting a

> parse error before '@' token

referring to the `@property int numerator, denominator;` statement in the Fraction.h file.

Here is the Fraction.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction : NSObject
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}

@property int numerator, denominator;

-(void) print;
-(void) setTo: (int) n over: (int) d;
-(double) convertToNum;

@end
```

Here is the Fraction.m file:

```
#import "Fraction.h"

@implementation Fraction

@synthesize numerator, denominator;

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}
-(void) setTo: (int) n over: (int) d
{
    numerator = n;
    denominator = d;
}
-(double) convertToNum
{
    if (denominator != 0)
        return (double) numerator/denominator;
    else
        return 1.0;
}

@end
```

Any help in understand why I am getting that parse error is much appreciated.

Comment: That compiles absolutely fine for me.  Are you using an ancient version of Xcode?  Or are you compiling for OS X 10.4?

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code from a website or a PDF, or use a source file that you downloaded from the internet? I have had trouble before with non-standard "whitespace" characters that fooled the compiler.

Comment: Yes, I am using an "ancient" version: OS X 10.4.11 and XCode 2.5!  Is that the problem?

Comment: ...and to answer the second question, I typed all the code in myself.  But thank you for raising that question.

Comment: I don't think `@property` is available on Tiger. Isn't Obj-C 2.0 Leopard and up?

Comment: I found this on Objective-C 2.0 (but interestingly not in Kochan's book):  "All Objective-C applications developed for Mac OS X that make use of the [above] improvements for Objective-C 2.0 are incompatible with all operating systems prior to 10.5 (Leopard)."  So we've found the explanation.  Thank you all.

Comment: Great! Please consider taking a moment to add this explanation as an answer and mark it accepted, so that the question does not appear in searches as "Unanswered".

Answer (score 3):

I found this on Objective-C 2.0 (but interestingly not in Kochan's book): "All Objective-C applications developed for Mac OS X that make use of the [above] improvements for Objective-C 2.0 are incompatible with all operating systems prior to 10.5 (Leopard)." So we've found the explanation. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Scolfax
welcome 
it seems your problem in
@property int numerator, denominator; and
NSLog(@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);